# Absolute convergence implies convergence .

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Absolute convergence implies that

$    \mid \mid s_m\mid −\mid s_n \mid \mid  \space = \space \mid \mid x_{m}\mid +\mid x_{m−1}\mid +…\mid x_{n+1} \mid \mid \space \leq \space ϵ $

But $\mid s_m −s_n\mid \space = \space\mid x_{m} + x_{m-1} +… x_{n+1}\mid $

$ \because \space  \mid x_{m} + x_{m−1} +… x_{n+1}\mid  $ $\leq$ $  \mid \mid x_{m}\mid +\mid x_{m−1}\mid +…\mid x_{n+1} \mid \mid $ = $  \mid \mid s_m\mid −\mid s_n \mid \mid  $

So $\space \mid s_m −s_n\mid \space \leq$  $  \mid \mid s_m\mid −\mid s_n \mid \mid  $

Which is a contradiction. What is wrong in this ?

Comment: I guess that $s_n = \sum_{i=0}^n x_i$, right?For $m>n$, $|s_m| - |s_n| = \left| \sum_{i=0}^m x_i \right| - \left| \sum_{i=0}^n x_i \right|$, so could you justify your first equality?

Comment: $| |x_{m-1}| + \cdots + |x_{n+1} || \neq ||s_m| -|s_n||$.

Comment: Can you give the correction ?